# Can't get location using onLocationChanged

Tags: android

I have been trying to get location from my android application for a long time. I am still unable to fetch the location. the onLocationChanged is not getting called.

MapsActivity2.java

```
public class MapsActivity2 extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    //Location location1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps2);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Missing",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Bus Location"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,17.0f));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity2.this, "Please Enable GPS and Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
        else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    LatLng latLng=new LatLng(latitude,longitude);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Bus Location"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,17.0f));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String s)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity2.this, "Please Enable GPS and Internet", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
        /*location1=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if(location1!=null)
        {
            double latitude = location1.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location1.getLongitude();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Bus Location"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 17.0f));
        }*/
    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good tutorial, may help you. https://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: `else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))` Remove the `else`.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things could change the result. The first one seems permission, so if the app isn't granted to use them then it'll be returned and wont make any location request.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ...
    return;
}
```

Others could be statuses of providers. So if they are not enabled, wont make any location request too

One for network provider

```
if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
```

And gps provider

```
if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
```

---

This code is also error-prone.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED 
    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, 
    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    ...
    return;
}
```

You saying there,  don't work if gps **and** network permissions aren't granted. But work if **any** of them granted.

Then you are making location requests without knowing which one is granted.

Finally, causing the not granted one will throw `SecurityException`

Comment: When i removed these, if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))   and if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) . The app crashed.

Comment: I didn't say remove those lines. BTW, whats the crash log says ?

Comment: After a crash, it worked. Now i am able to get the lat and long. Just had to take the two conditions out.

Comment: @MathewsPMathew good to hear. Just check my last edit on answer, could be helpful to identify the crash you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `new LocationListener()` in this line `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener()` .

Create a listener object and use that, or simply use `this`.

```
new LocationListener()
```

is different which you're accessing .

Comment: _Don't use new LocationListener() in this line locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener()_ What's the reason of not using new location listener instance ?

Comment: It's already passed to last parameter of `requestLocationUpdates` anonymously. What's wrong with this usage to cause not firing `LocationListener` methods ?

Comment: Didn't run topic owner's code, but there is no need arguing about passing anonymous listener, it works.